# SciPy installation Win10 32 bit failed on metadata creation

Tags: installation, scipy, metadata

I was using advise e.g. [metadata-generation-failed while installing Scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565108/metadata-generation-failed-while-installing-scipy) . Did not help
Numpy and astropy have been installed without any problem.
Python Version is 3.10

Here the message screen

`C:\Users\ibm>pip install scipy --pre
Collecting scipy
Using cached scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
Installing backend dependencies ... done
Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [21 lines of output]
+ meson setup --prefix=C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310-32 C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8 C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8.mesonpy-cm0evbed\build --native-file=C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8.mesonpy-native-file.ini -Ddebug=false -Doptimization=2
The Meson build system
Version: 1.1.0
Source dir: C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8
Build dir: C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8.mesonpy-cm0evbed\build
Build type: native build
Project name: SciPy
Project version: 1.10.1
WARNING: Failed to activate VS environment: Could not find C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe

```
  ..\..\meson.build:1:0: ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
  The following exception(s) were encountered:
  Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `cc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `gcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `clang --version` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `clang-cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"
  Running `pgcc --version` gave "[WinError 2] Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden"

  A full log can be found at C:\Users\ibm\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mc8y85cu\scipy_575e50a3f5a44cc58f88c1fb568aaad8\.mesonpy-cm0evbed\build\meson-logs\meson-log.txt
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.`

I also could not find the full log file.

Do I need MS Visual Studio installed?
I am not sure to get it for an old Win10 32bit system.
The machine on which I want to use some functions of scipy has a small harddrive and is used in my in a amateur observatory.
So I prefer not to install the big package of Visual Studio.
Are there some alternatives ?

Looking through stackoverflow and other sources in the web. Applied the methods that I found.
Updated pip and install tools.